# Is this sentence grammatically correct "There are only 3 students signed for this course."?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

Or it should be " There are only 3 students who signed up for this course." ?

What about " There are some people talking in the room."

What topic of grammar should I read to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences look grammatically correct to me. I think people are more likely to say "... signed up for this course."

I cannot tell on what topic you're looking for more information.

Answer (score 1):

“There are only 3 students signed for this course.” sounds a bit strange.

If I were you, I would say the second sentence you mentioned:

> There are only 3 students who signed up for this course.

I would recommend adding the "who" as you did in the second example. It would say the students that signed up. As mentioned in the [dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=who+meaning#dobs=who), the second meaning of "who" is:

> 2. used to introduce a clause giving further information about a person or people previously mentioned.
>    "Joan Fontaine plays the mouse who married the playboy"

So adding a "who" would sound better and more grammatical.

Your first way of saying the sentence I wouldn't prefer.

---

For your last sentence:

> There are some people talking in the room.

That is definitely proper grammar, it mentioned "some" as well, so it's a proper sentence.